# Will creating a custom dns record during signup cause potential issues?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

If you have a hosted application, that when customers signup, they choose a subdomain like:

```
customer1234.example.com
```

When they do this, I want to create a custom dns record that will map to a specific i.p address.

The reason is for sharding users to different clusters.

If I do this, when the customer finishes signup up, **it might take a while for the url customer123.example.com to resolve correct?**

Answer (score 4):

DNS records are created and updated instantly. It might take longer if you're using a third party service for DNS, but then that's because they purposely slow it down (for instance, Linode applies DNS changes made through their web panel every 15 minutes).

If you *change* DNS records, then it might take a while for the various DNS servers on the internet to drop the existing record off their cache, but the actual update on the server is instant.